# How to send packet without link-layer header using Npcap?

Tags: c++, npcap

How can I send a packet with Npcap, without having to create link-layer header yourself?

Comment: By following the documentation. Is there a specific question about something you’ve tried and can’t get working?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I send a packet with Npcap, without having to create link-layer header yourself?

By using a higher-level library that runs atop libpcap/WinPcap/Npcap and that constructs link-layer headers for you. There are such libraries, at least for UN*Xes, and some might have Windows binary versions; I don't know their names offhand.

libpcap/WinPcap/Npcap *themselves* don't provide a general mechanism for doing that; they leave the job of parsing and generating packet headers to code that uses them.